# Creating WPF ListView animation effect

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, animation, storyboard

I'm currently working on WPF ListView items moving animation and I'm actually stuck on it.
Do you have an idea how to create animation effect of moving item when I remove it from index x' of a ListView  and insert to index y'? (x'>y' and vise-versa).

Comment: What are you actually stuck on? Can you post your code?

Comment: A more generalized solution might be to create an "animated panel" that animates elements as they are added or removed from the panel.  Then you can use that panel in the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of the `ListView`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you please post your xaml and code, so it's easier for people to help you?

Comment: Interestingly enough, Windows Store apps already do this. You may want to try and figure out what they are doing, the code will be pretty similar.